# autopair.el takes over my enter button used in autocomplete.el

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

When writing code, I come across autocomplete suggestions and when I press enter autocomplete completes my words with the suggestions. 
But ever since I started using autopair.el, the enter merely goes to the other line in the same situations. I have to use tab. 
I went thorough the autopair.el to see if I could change something and get this fixed, but was beyond me.

Did someone happen to find the same a problem and come up with a solution.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in my setup. Could you please provide information about your Emacs/autopair/auto-complete versions?

Comment: The autocomplete version is 1.3.1 and autopair version is 0.4 . emacs version is GNU emacs 23.3.1

Comment: I have autopair 0.4, auto-complete 1.4 and emacs 23.2.1. Maybe you could try upgrading auto-complete...

Comment: alright . I'll try that. Just to make sure. When you press enter, the autocomplete word gets added. And you don't have to essentially hit tabs, right ?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I only have to press `RET`, no `TAB` needed.